# How to detect that workbench part was docked to another window in Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have Eclipse RCP application with two windows.
Each window contain some views/editors.
Once view/editor is moved from one window to another I need to perform some operation. So, I need somehow detect that part was docked in another window.

For now the only solution I found is to compare part's workbench window and E4 model window on each `partActivated` event:

```
IEditorPart editor = ...
MPart editorPart = (MPart) editor.getSite().getService(MPart.class);
EModelService modelService =  editorPart.getContext().get(EModelService.class);
MWindow window = modelService.getTopLevelWindowFor(editorPart);
IWorkbenchWindow workbenchWindow = window.getContext().get(IWorkbenchWindow.class);
if (workbenchWindow != editor.getSite().getWorkbenchWindow()) {
    // Editor was docked to another window
    ...
}
```

This approach works because once part is moved to another window its `editor.getSite().getWorkbenchWindow()` window points to old window and window obtained from E4 model points to window in which part resists currently.

But this looks ugly and there should be better solution.

Comment: Have you tried using `IPartListener` on the two windows to see if you get part events?

Comment: When part docked to another window `IPartListener` receive `partActivated` event. It does not allow to determine whether part was docked or only activated.